# Overriding object in belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, overriding, belongs-to

I have such models:

```
class User
  belongs_to :authenticity
end

class Authenticity
  has_one :user
end
```

now I create authenticity for user:

```
u = User.first; u.authenticity = Authenticity.create
```

and now I assign new authenticity:

```
u.authenticity = Authenticity.create
```

now I have in my database two authenticities:

```
irb(main):035:0> Authenticity.all
  Authenticity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "authenticities".* FROM "authenticities"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
     #<Authenticity id: 22, token: nil, created_at: "2015-09-15 08:18:09", updated_at: "2015-09-15 08:18:46", user_id: nil>, 
     #<Authenticity id: 23, token: nil, created_at: "2015-09-15 08:18:45", updated_at: "2015-09-15 08:18:46", user_id: "1">
   ]>
```

One which belongs to user and one without any user (`user_id: nil`). What I want is to create new authenticity and do not store authenticities with `nil`s in `user_id` field. I'm currently destroying the old one manually, but I'm curious if I can say somehow rails to do it for me. I don't want to use `after_create` however. Is there some solution for this?

Comment: Who belongs to whom? the table that belongs to another, you have to add the foreign key column in it nor vise versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing two records because you are creating them twice, do this instead

```
u = User.first 
u.create_authenticity
```

You can enforce a check before creating an `Authenticity` record

```
u.authenticity ||= Authenticity.create
```

If you want to delete the old `Authenticity` record with the new one then do this

```
if u.authenticity
  u.authenticity.destroy
  u.authenticity = Authenticity.create
end
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, the point is I want to create new one and delete old one from a database in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  has_one :authenticity
end

class Authenticity
  belongs_to :user
end

u = User.first
u.authenticate = Authenticate.create
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Authenticity object twice. That's why you have two records in you database. Also you have `belongs_to` which specifies a one-to-one association with `Authenticity` class. When you create new record for associations Rails, of course, doesn't remove previous object. If you need to remove associated object you should do it explicitly.